# could not broadcast input array

Tags: python, numpy, mnist

I have a csv data, the first column of the data is 'label' and columns after the first one to the end 784 column contains a representation of an image (28*28) format.

I created a tuple of numpy array using the following function.

Next step is I am trying to split this dataset into desired 80% /20% split for training and validation. For that, I use `loadData()` method as below. When I run the function to split, I get error  **could not broadcast input array from shape (5851,784) into shape (5851) error.**

My question here is I just want to split the available tuple generated using `load(filename)` into two datasets. Any help?

```
filename=dir_path+'train1.csv'
def load(filename):
    # read file into a list of rows
    with open(filename, 'rU') as csvfile:
        lines = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        rows = list(lines)

    # create empty numpy arrays of the required size
    data = np.empty((len(rows), len(rows[0])-1), dtype=np.float64)
    expected = np.empty((len(rows),), dtype=np.int64)

    # fill array with data from the csv-rows
    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        data[i,:] = row[1:]
        expected[i] = row[0]

    training_data = data, expected
    return training_data

print load(filename)
```

**Result**

```
 (array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           ..., 
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]))
```

**Run this function to split:**

```
def loadData():
    train_data= load(train_name)
    #test_data= load(test_name)

    training_data,validation_data =np.split(train_data, [int(.8 * len(train_data))])

    return train_data

print loadData()
```

**Result:** 
could not broadcast input array from shape (5851,784) into shape (5851)

> **SOLUTION:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_name=dir_path+'train8.csv'

test_name=dir_path+'test8.csv'

def load(filename):
    # read file into a list of rows
    with open(filename, 'rU') as csvfile:
        lines = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        rows = list(lines)

    # create empty numpy arrays of the required size
    data = np.empty((len(rows), len(rows[0])-1), dtype=np.float64)
    expected = np.empty((len(rows),), dtype=np.int64)

    # fill array with data from the csv-rows
    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        data[i,:] = row[1:]
        expected[i] = row[0]

    result_data = data, expected
    return result_data

def loadData():
    train_data= load(train_name)[0]
    labels= load(train_name)[1]
    test_data= load(test_name)

    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_data, labels, test_size=0.33)

    training_data = (x_train, y_train)
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test)

    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)
```

This solution will match the mnist data set

Comment: Why not just slice the data: `train_data[:int(.8 * len(train_data))])`? Also, you might want to checkout `pandas.read_csv` for loading the CSV file into an array.

Comment: os if I run that fucntion, it splits the first array only, I do not know where other array from the tuple goes:  (array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]]),)

Comment: The problem is you are returning two arrays from the `load`. You need to unpack these and slice them individually so that you have four arrays; your input variables and output variable for both the training and validation set. You should probably get rid of `load` entirely, use `pandas.read_csv`, slice the result 80/20 and then split each of those into your input and output variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you are passing a tuple consisting of one matrix and one array (that does not have the same shape) to `np.split` which is why you get the broadcast error. It works fine if you give `np.split` a single matrix:

```
train_data = np.zeros((5000, 784))
labels = np.zeros(5000)

train,test = np.split(train_data, [int(0.8 * len(train_data))])
print "Train: {0}, Test: {1}".format(train.shape, test.shape)
```

This gives the following output:

```
Train: (4000, 784), Test: (1000, 784)
```

While if you pass it a tuple of a matrix and an array:

```
train_data = np.zeros((5000, 784))
labels = np.zeros(5000)

train,test = np.split((train_data,labels), [int(0.8 *len(train_data))])
```

You get the broadcast error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5000,784) into shape (5000)
```

If you want to split a dataset, including its labels, I would suggest using something like [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) from `scikit learn` (available through `pip install sklearn`) which can handle both observations and labels using the same function:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def loadData():

    train_data = np.zeros((5000, 784))
    labels = np.zeros(5000)
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_data, labels, test_size=0.22)

    print "Training samples: {0}, training labels: {1}".format(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
    print "Validation samples: {0}, validation labels: {1}".format(x_test.shape, y_test.shape)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loadData()
```

Output:

```
Training samples: (3900, 784), training labels: (3900,)
Validation samples: (1100, 784), validation labels: (1100,)
```